Couldn't Build app : Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
I'm having trouble running my Flutter app on Android, and I'm encountering an error during the build process.
This is the error i am facing and i am not able to build my app
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider_android:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\shahi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\shahi.gradle\caches\transforms-3\9263d05e7a9236c2cfa2ca39c5a20e5a\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\shahi.gradle\caches\transforms-3\9263d05e7a9236c2cfa2ca39c5a20e5a\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 22s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Yesterday,
i updated my flutter,dart and Android Studio and currently i am using Android Studio LadyBug and i am not able to build my app
I have tried reinstalling android studio,plugins and all the solutions that were previous available such as updating Android Command Line Tools from SDK Manager. I have checked all my environment variables and its all correct. The issue started as i updated my flutter,dart and android studio.
I have tried Flutter clean,flutter pub get etc.

Update com.android.application plugin to version 8.3.2 or latest in settings.gradle file.
If you can't find this file you can create one at root of Android folder of Flutter project and copy paste below content:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    }

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.3.2" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.21" apply false
}

include ":app"


Change to 8.3.2 in

Setting.gradle

id "com.android.application" version "8.3.2" apply false

Change to 8.4 or 8.5 in

Gradlewrapper.properties

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-all.zip

change Ndkversion to
ndkVersion '25.1.8937393'


I faced issues with my project nearing the deadline, so I downgraded Android Studio to get it working. While I understand this is a temporary solution, I haven’t upgraded again because the latest version wasn’t working for me.

faced the same issue, downgraded my java from version 23 to 17 and it worked.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
